# meteorjs Accounts.createUser not working anymore

Tags: javascript, meteor

The Accounts.createUser method does not work anymore. A few days ago everything works fine and i am sure that i did not change anything.

I have a form for registration. On submit click the following code will executed:

**Edit** i forgot to say that this function is in a meteor method so it will be executed on client & server

```
var newUserData = {
            username : post.email,
            password : post.pwd,
            email : post.email,
            profile: {
                first_name : post.first_name,
                last_name : post.last_name,
                register : ''
            }
        };
        console.log('### new user data ###');
        console.log(newUserData);
        var newUserCreated = Accounts.createUser(newUserData, function(e){
            console.log('### createuser callback ###');
            console.log(e);
        });
        console.log(newUserCreated);
```

The "newUserData" returns a valid object. This one in my example:

```
{ 
username: 'info@email.com',
password: 'mypassword',
email: 'info@email.com',
profile: 
{ first_name: 'wadwad',
last_name: 'wadawd',
register: '' } 
}
```

This console log is on client side and server side equal.

The createuser callback just works on client side and returns:

```
Error: No result from call to createUser
```

newUserCreated returns nothing - not on client and not on server side.

Any ideas what this error means ? Cant find a reference on google.

**Edit 2**
If its important to know: The createUser method worked fine until now. I dont change anything in the method where createUser is in it. I already created with this function users and with the Accounts-package i am able to login with these accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the callback from createUser. This is a bit stupid I think. The Callback just works in Client side and not on Server side - but when executing the method with a callback on the server side the server crashes and no user will be added.

Its a bit strange but what ever - remove the callback and everything is fine.